# How do I create a website where content changes on scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, parallax

I would like to create a homepage where, as the user scrolls, the content changes. Let's say the user scrolls to position y and there an image should pop in, when he leaves position y it should go away. 
Is this purely done on the basis of scroll position or is there any other 'trick' before I start doing something stupid ? 
I am pretty sure this is achieved with jQuery but I just want the underlying technique.

Something like this http://dentsunetwork.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use javascript for that.

Basically you add a  scroll event to your body like:

```
$(body).scroll(function() {
    if ( $this).scrollTop() > 200 ) {
        $('#someElement').css('display', 'block');
        $('#someOtherElement').css('display', 'block');    
    }
});
```

When you scroll more then 200 pixels `someElement` and `someOtherElement` would become visible.

Elements with id `someElement` and `someOtherElement` would have to be `display: none;` at the start.

You can expand this by adding ie. `$this).scrollTop() > 400` and displaying other elements.

You can ofcourse also do this by making classes like `showAt300` and using that in a selector to show all those elements by setting those to `display: block;`

The above method can ofcourse also make items hide again at certain positions by setting `display: none;` instead.

I haven't tested the example above, but atleast it should get you started.

References:

- Scroll event: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/
- Scroll position: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery Parallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/). [See here for more examples of sites that use it](http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/21-examples-of-parallax-scrolling-in-web-design).

Comment: Argh.. I hate it when the answer to jquery questions is: use this plugin.. How will people ever learn anything if they just copy from others >.<

Comment: @DamienOvereem The theory is always interesting, but many SO users have a task that needs finishing within a time frame not set by themselves. This answer caters to those users.

Comment: Unfortunatly in this case the QA asked for a way to display or hide content based on scroll position. Paralax does not do that.